# EINVAL when trying write() on a ashmem_create_region fd

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ashmem

I am trying to get a memfd on Android. When I do this all things seem to be okay:

```cpp
int getFd() {
    ...
    int fd = syscall(__NR_memfd_create, "none", MFD_CLOEXEC | MFD_ALLOW_SEALING);
    errno = 0;
    write(fd, str.c_str(), str.length());
    logi(strerror(errno));
    lseek(fd, SEEK_SET, SEEK_SET);
    return fd;
}
```

But *memfd_create* syscall doesn't exist on older Android version. So I am trying to call *ashmem_create_region* in *libcutils.so* instead. (Not using ASharedMemory_create because the minSDK 26 is still too high)
First I inject into zygote to dlsym the symbols.

```cpp
// Should call in zygote through Riru
void initMemoryTools() {
    void *handle = dlopen("/system/lib/libcutils.so", RTLD_LAZY);
#define DLSYM(symbol, type) symbol = reinterpret_cast<type>(dlsym(handle, #symbol))
    DLSYM(ashmem_valid,           int (*)(int));
    DLSYM(ashmem_create_region,   int (*)(const char *, size_t));
    DLSYM(ashmem_set_prot_region, int (*)(int, int));
    DLSYM(ashmem_pin_region,      int (*)(int, size_t, size_t));
    DLSYM(ashmem_unpin_region,    int (*)(int, size_t, size_t));
    DLSYM(ashmem_get_size_region, int (*)(int));
#undef DLSYM
}
```

Then I replace *memfd_create* for *ashmem_create_region*.

```cpp
int getFd() {
    ...
    int fd = ashmem_create_region("none", sizeof(char) * str.length());
    errno = 0;
    write(fd, str.c_str(), str.length());
    logi(strerror(errno));
    lseek(fd, SEEK_SET, SEEK_SET);
    return fd;
}
```

I successfully get a fd (not -1), but write() throws EINVAL, also encounter EBADF when trying to read from this fd.
Now I wonder why this happens and what should I do to get a memfd on Android 7 ~ 11?

Comment: Can you successfully use the region with `mmap` instead of `read` and `write`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thank you! After mmap, now I can both read and write the fd the same way as memfd_create. The only one thing I'm not sure is why it works by doing this.

Comment: Does `read` work after you put some data in it through `mmap`?